# how i can add "/" to preg_match in php?

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
preg_match("/[^-+*%0-9]+/", $your_string, $matches)
```

It works great but I would like to be able to add the "/" character and I don't know how.

Comment: By using it like `\/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a different pattern delimiter, such as a hash, instead of a forward slash, and then just match the forward slash like any other character:

```
preg_match('#^/#', $subject);
```

Answer (score 3):

Such expressions needs to escaped, so you can use it like the following:

```
 preg_match("/[^-+\/*%0-9]+/", $your_string, $matches)
```